# SELECT rows while performing operation for each row with previous one as argument

Tags: sql, db2, relational-database, db2-luw

Let's say I have a table of something like:

```
+-------+
| FIELD |
+-------+
| 1000  |
| 1200  |
| 1300  |
| 900   |
| 1400  |
+-------+
```

How can I perform `SELECT` query to retrieve rows `0..N`, but instead of getting their values, get arithmetical difference with each row's previous row, i. e. `RESULT(N) = ROW(N) - ROW(N-1)` ? I expect to get something like:

```
+--------------+
| RESULT       |
+--------------+
| (EMPTY OR 0) |
| 200          |
| 100          |
| -400         |
| 500          |
+--------------+
```

I'm using `DB2`. It will be really cool if you provide me with some portable response that is not specific to a particular SQL DBMS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ThitLwinOo: no, got no primary keys yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `LAG` function. it exists in multiple databases including [db2](/questions/tagged/db2)

Syntax would be something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(MyField, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY MyID ORDER BY SomeThing ) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE MyField - LAG(MyField, 1) OVER ( PARTITION BY MyID ORDER BY SomeThing )
       END AS Result
    FROM MyTable
```

[Documentation on `LAG` from IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-10-9)

Comment: Readers should understand this answer is platform specific, and applies only to DB2 for LUW, not z/OS or IBM i.

Comment: Readers should also be aware that the sample database from the question has no column by which to order; there is therefore no guaranteed single set of results returned.